# Iterate through all rows in table PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

From table1 I would like to gather values from certain columns. First of all I have tried to copy one table to another but I stuck when tried to:

```
for row in row_count
    for column in column_count
        insert into table2 at (x,y) value from (row,column)
        column++
    end
row++
end
```

My first function to count how many rows is:

```
create or replace FUNCTION func_count_rows(table_name IN varchar2,
debug boolean default false)
RETURN number IS
   total number(2) := 0;
BEGIN

IF debug = true THEN 

DBMS_OUTPUT.put('Function count rows: ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('select count(*) from ' || table_name || ';');
DBMS_OUTPUT.put('Returns: ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');

   END IF;


execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || table_name into total;

   RETURN total;
END;
```

Then my procedure to first print values but I stuck here:

```
create or replace procedure gather_values (rows_quantity in VARCHAR2,
    column_count in VARCHAR2,
    debug boolean default false
    )
    is begin

    select 


    FOR i IN 1..rows_quantity LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('#### ROW 1 ####');

        FOR i IN 1..94 LOOP

            END LOOP;

        END LOOP;
    end;
```

I don't know how to get column quantity and value from exact (x,y) of table.

Could you kindly help me? Thank you.

I have forget to tell that I'm using oracle SQL enviroment.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, this has nothing in common with PL/SQL:

```
for row in row_count
    for column in column_count
        insert into table2 at (x,y) value from (row,column)
        column++
    end
row++
end
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm).

To copy all rows from one table to another:

```
insert into table2 (x,y) 
select a, b
  from table1;
```

It is a simple SQL query, it can be used as is or inside a PL/SQL procedure.

There is a lot of possibilities to iterate all rows of a table. The most simple:

```
for i in (select column1, column2, ... from table1) loop
  dbms_output.put_line(i.column1);
end loop;
```

Another ways:

1. Using cursors
2. Using collections
3. Using dynamic SQL and dbms_sql package

To count rows in a table, you can use SQL query:

```
select count(*)
  from table1
```

or almost the same PL/SQL code (you don't need to use `execute immediate`):

```
declare
  total number;
begin
select count(*)
  into total
  from table1;
  dbms_output.put_line('count of rows: ' || total);
end;
/
```

But in any case you don't need to know, how many rows and columns a table contains, to iterate them. You need only to know, how to filter, which of them you want to iterate.

Comment: Care! none of these 3 solutions work on Oracle databese